# C++ calculate the approximate value of pi

Tags: c++

folks
I am going to calculate the approximate value of pi by using following formula:
pi = 4 [ 1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/9 . . . + ((-1)^n)/(2n + 1) ]

I am supposed to use the while loop to import term, get the value and repeat the process again and again until I import a -1 to quit.

In my code, the first output is right but when I import following one, the output is not right.

What's wrong with my code?
Thanks!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int terms;
    int terms_;
    double pi = 1 ;

    {
       cout.setf(ios::fixed);
       cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
       cout.precision(3);
       cout<<"Enter the value of the parameter 'n' in the Leibniz formula (or -1 to quit):"<<endl;
       cin>>terms;

       while(terms > -1)

           {
              for(int i = 1; i<=terms ; i++)
              {
                pi += 4 * (pow(-1.0,i))/((2*i)+1);
               }
             pi += 3
             terms_ = terms + 1;
             cout << "The approximate value of pi using "<< terms_ << " terms is:"<< pi <<endl;

              cout<<"Enter the value of the parameter 'n' in the Leibniz formula (or -1 to quit):"<<endl;
               cin>>terms;
                 }
             }
```

}

Comment: You should figure out what's wrong using your debugger and stepping through your code line by line. You will quickly see where you've done wrong in your code, just take a look how the variables are changing when you step through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int terms;
    int terms_;
    double pi = 1 ;

    {    
       cout.setf(ios::fixed);
       cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
       cout.precision(3);
       cout<<"Enter the value of the parameter 'n' in the Leibniz formula     
       (or -1 to quit):"<<endl;
       cin>>terms;

       while(terms > -1)

           {
              pi = 1;
              for(int i = 1; i<=terms ; i++)
              {
                pi += 4 * (pow(-1.0,i))/((2*i)+1);
               }
             pi += 3;
             terms_ = terms + 1;
             if(terms > 1)
             cout << "The approximate value of pi using "<< terms_ ;
            cout<<"terms is:"<< pi <<endl;

              cout<<"Enter the value of the parameter 'n' in the Leibniz 
             formula (or -1 to quit):"<<endl;
               cin>>terms;
                 }
             }
```

Comment: this is what i mean

Comment: Why didn't you just edit your original answer? It seems like you posted 3 answers to this. You should fix your formatting too.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int terms;
    int terms_;
    double pi = 1 ;

    {    
       cout.setf(ios::fixed);
       cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
       cout.precision(3);
       cout<<"Enter the value of the parameter 'n' in the Leibniz formula     
       (or -1 to quit):"<<endl;
       cin>>terms;

       while(terms > -1)

           {
              pi = 1;
              for(int i = 1; i<=terms ; i++)
              {
                pi += 4 * (pow(-1.0,i))/((2*i)+1);
               }
             pi += 3
             terms_ = terms + 1;
             cout << "The approximate value of pi using "<< terms_ << " 
            terms is:"<< pi <<endl;

              cout<<"Enter the value of the parameter 'n' in the Leibniz 
             formula (or -1 to quit):"<<endl;
               cin>>terms;
                 }
             }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! And another thing is when I import 1, the cout  << "The approximate value of pi using "<< terms_ << " terms is:"<< pi <<endl; must become "term is:" Do you know how to deal with that? Thanks!

Comment: could you tell me where should I put it? I am confused.

Answer (score -2):

You miss this.

```
while(term > -1)
{
   pi = 1;
   ...
}
```

try again.

Comment: It's already done before the loop, and assigning inside would be wrong.

Comment: do not write double inside.

Comment: _"do not write double inside."_ What do you mean?